# Why does Flow ignore the possibility of undefined when accessing an array element?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

This function has a bug in it. `capitalize('')` would throw a

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`.

```
// @flow

function capitalize(str: string) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
}
```

This is because

```
var a = "foo" // : string
var b = a[0] // also : string
```

But why is flow inferring that `b` is a `string` instead of a `string|void` which seems to be the correct type for `b`?

This can be forced with a typecast

`return (str[0]: string|void).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)`

Comment: You're trying to access an index of an empty array. You'd need to have a null check for your `capitalize` function or is there a way to enforce non-null arguments with flowtype?

Comment: Sounds like, arguably, a bug in flow. I'd suggest [filing a report on their GitHub page.](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues) Make sure you check to see if one is already filed first.

Comment: Flow apparently assumes that the array index is valid, and all elements of strings are also strings.

Comment: Seems like an implementation bug to me, unless flow is something like TypeScript and can enforce non-nullable types.

Comment: @Barmar I'd like to know the reasoning behind assuming that array indexes will be strictly non-nullable. I'm sceptical that this is a bug. This behaviour must be some kind of a correctness tradeoff.

Comment: Because `?string` would mean "nullable" string. But since primitives are not nullable by default, it could only be a string or undefined (i.e. void) and array elements are never assumed to be undefined.

Comment: @RedMercury Only the developers behind Flow could give you an exact answer. We can only give guesses.

Comment: Btw, this is why you should use `.charAt(0)` :-)

Comment: @RedMercury Yes, of course it's a correctness tradeoff. If you use indexed access (whether on arrays or strings), it is expected that you only use valid indices (as you usually would anyway). Flow is not powerful enough to prove this of course. But if it assumed every access could return `undefined`, it would throw a lot of errors/warnings for the correct cases as well (or force you to suppress them).

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. `var a = [1]; var b = a[100]` Yeah, it can make sense to infer  `b` as a `number`. Even though it's not safe to do so it's going to prevent a lot of false positives. Still surprising flow decided to do this since one of flows main design principles is correctness (no runtime exceptions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html#undefined-values-and-optional-types):

> **Undefined Values and Optional Types**
>
> Undefined values, just like `null`, can cause issues too. Unfortunately, undefined values are ubiquitous in JavaScript and it is hard to avoid them without severely affecting the usability of the language. For example, arrays can have holes for elements; object properties can be dynamically added and removed. Flow ignores the possibility of `undefined` resulting from object property and array element accesses. Being stricter would force the programmer to do `undefined` checks (like `null` checks) on each dereference of an array element or object property to get anything useful done.